# Recommended practice for appending a dataframe without renaming it?

Tags: r, coding-style

### Background

I am writing a script that constantly updates a dataframe:

```
 ## Step A calculations
 results <- data.frame(results.from.A)

 ## Step B calculations

 results <- rbind(results, results.from.B)

 ##At the end of script
 print(xtable(results))
```

But this reassignment of an existing object name `results <- f(results` seems that it could be bad practice.

I could also do:

```
 ##At the end of script
 results <- as.data.frame(rbind(results.from.A, results.from.B))
```

Or just add to a list

```
 results <- list()

 ## Step A calculations
 results[[A]] <- results.from.A

 ## Step B calculations

 results[[B]] <- results.from.B

 ##At the end of script
 print(xtable(as.data.frame(results)))
```

### Question

Which of these or other approaches is preferred?

Comment: How about just adding it... `results = data.frame(A=results.from.A)`, `results$B = results.from.B`, etc.

Comment: To me, rbinding the new data frame to the existing data frame with assignment to the existing data frame, as you do in your first example, seems fine.  It's the way I would do it.

Comment: Saving each data frame in a list, and putting everything together at the end, as you do in your last example, also seems fine.  I do both, depending on which feels more natural in context.

Comment: @Benjamin your method binds columns instead of rows, and thus would only work with vectors in which each element is the same type, e.g. not a mix of characters and numbers such as `c('a',1,2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my work flow, I create lists that I merge down. Here's an example.

```
a <- 1:10
my.fun <- function(x) { 
    data.frame(id = x, val = exp(x^2))
}

out <- lapply(X = as.list(a), FUN = my.fun)
class(out)
out <- do.call("rbind", out)

> out
   id          val
1   1 2.718282e+00
2   2 5.459815e+01
3   3 8.103084e+03
4   4 8.886111e+06
5   5 7.200490e+10
6   6 4.311232e+15
7   7 1.907347e+21
8   8 6.235149e+27
9   9 1.506097e+35
10 10 2.688117e+43
```

It's up to you to decide how to construct a list, it can even be done using a "regular" loop.

*Addendum*

It's generally not recommended to grow an object (at least pre-allocate it). You can read more about this in [R Inferno](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/s/Spoetry/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: I second this workflow.  Using `do.call` with `rbind` is such a common thing that I wonder whether it should be made a function in its own right.

Comment: @RichieCotton: rbind.list <- function(...) {
  L <- list(...)
  do.call(rbind,L[[1]])
}

Comment: See plyr::rbind.fill which is also faster than do.call plus rbind